# SIGINT not being propagated to background child process

Tags: bash, process, kill, background-process, signals

I need to send `SIGINT` to terminate a process gracefully but I can't.

This is a sample, because the environment in which the execution occurs is 'unknown' (a bash script in travis.com)

I managed to get (simulate) the same behaviour, by launching a process like this `(command &) &`

```
vagrant@host:~$ (sleep 40 &) &
[1] 8473
vagrant@host:~$ ps -o pid,pgid,args
  PID  PGID COMMAND                     
 2787  2787 -bash                       
 8474  8473 sleep 40                    
 8490  8490 ps -o pid,pgid,args  
[1]+  Done                    ( sleep 40 & )
vagrant@host:~$ kill -INT 8474  ##### here I send SIGINT to the process
vagrant@host:~$ kill -INT -8473 ##### here I send SIGINT to the process group
vagrant@host:~$ ps -o pid,pgid,args
  PID  PGID COMMAND                     
 2787  2787 -bash                       
 8474  8473 sleep 40                    
 8559  8559 ps -o pid,pgid,args
```

I googled and read a lot about signals and groups and I can't understand what is happening here. Is the signal being ignored at some point? What is happening? How can I send `SIGINT` to that `sleep` process?

**EDIT**: if `SIGTERM` is used, the process is killed (maybe the parent subshell is killed?)

Answer (score 4):

In order to have a non-interactive job respond to SIGINT, you need to create a handler for SIGINT:

```
$ ( (trap "echo Got SigInt" SIGINT; sleep 60) & ) &
[1] 13619
$ 
[1]+  Done                    ( ( trap "echo Got SigInt" SIGINT; sleep 60 ) & )
$ ps -o pid,pgid,args
  PID  PGID COMMAND
11972 11972 bash
13620 13619 bash
13621 13619 sleep 60
13622 13622 ps -o pid,pgid,args
$ kill -INT 13620
$ kill -INT 13621
$ Got SigInt
```

#### Sending SIGINT to the sleep process

As Stéphane Chazelas suggests in the comments, if the goal is to return to the default behavior of SIGINT, we can just use `trap - SIGINT`.  For example:

```
$ ( (trap - SIGINT; sleep 60) & ) &
[1] 16690
$ ps -o pid,pgid,args
  PID  PGID COMMAND
11972 11972 bash
16691 16690 bash
16692 16690 sleep 60
16693 16693 ps -o pid,pgid,args
[1]+  Done                    ( ( trap - SIGINT; sleep 60 ) & )
$ kill -INT 16692
$ ps -o pid,pgid,args
  PID  PGID COMMAND
11972 11972 bash
16698 16698 ps -o pid,pgid,args
```

Comment: Great! Then, to send the SIGINT to the 'sleep' process, how should the trap command be?

Comment: Or just `trap - INT` to reset the handler to its default.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas was the other answer yours? because it helped me to solve the problem by using the perl script, I was going to accept it, but found that was deleted.

Comment: jperelli, I just added  @StéphaneChazelas suggestion to the answer for how to get SIGINT to act as usual along with an example showing its use.

Comment: @jperelli No, it was [Gareth Rees](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/152036/gareth-rees). His answer was correct for bash 4.2 and earlier and several other shells. Not sure why he deleted it.

Comment: What makes a process an "interactive job" ? For example would calling "wait" make the backgrounded process interactive again ?